# Cast-in-place concrete anchor spacing

Tags: concrete

I am having a concrete slab poured in the back yard to support a kit gazebo.

The kit gazebo has 4 legs, each of which is secured to the foundation with 4 bolts.

I can, I believe, anchor the gazebo either by drilling holes in the slab after it has cured and using expanding anchors, or I can place J-bolts (or similar) in the concrete before it cures. (I will of course check with the AHJ for what's acceptable.)

If I go with cast-in-place anchors, the hole pattern on the gazebo legs requires rather precise placement.

My question is: what's the best way to achieve this placement? I'm thinking I could tack-weld the J-bolts to a spacer plate and sink the bolts in the concrete with the spacer plate resting on the top surface of the slab. If I do that, is there a certain material for the plate that I must or must not use? Is there a better way?

Comment: How close to the slab edge do you expect the bolts to be?

Comment: And what's "rather precise"? Can you simply provide the mason with one of the post bases and direct them to be sure the bolts fit the hole spacing? Actual post _position_ is probably less critical than the base holes.

Comment: If you go the cast-in-place route, make a template out of 1/8"-1/4" wood that matches the hole pattern in your gazebo feet and use it to finalize the bolt placement before the concrete cures.